# treating a one dimensional array as a two dimensional array for sorting

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

let's say I have a one-dimensional array of 100 elements. Is there a way that I can treat this array as a 10x10 two-dimensional array so I can perform a multi-parameter sort on it. I really do not want to store the contents of the original array into a new multidimensional array I just want a way to operate on the one-dimensional array as if it were two dimensional.

Comment: What's a multi-parameter sort on a 1D array? Please give us an example.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: What I mean by a multiparameter sort is that I am sorting in for two conditions. A good example of a multi-parameter sort is how the periodic table has is sorted by periodic trends such as atomic radius, electronegativity, etc.

Comment: You could start with a 1D array and treat it later as a 2D array in either row- or column-major form. The only caveat is that you would either need to perform some memory voodoo (see Lee Daniel Crocker's answer below), or, to be legal, implement your own indexing. For instance, for column-major case, assuming `a` is a 1D integer array, you could have `int get_at(int *a, size_t row, size_t j, size_t nrows) { return a[j * nrows + i]; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you can, but it isn't something that is generally recommended. Whether you are using a 1D array or you are using a 2D array, you are simply using X-amount of storage. You can use that block of memory however you like. When needing to store an "array-of-arrays" within that block you buy convenience by declaring the block as a 2D array, but there is no mandate you have to do it that way.

For instance, take your 100 elements example, if your 1D array contains 100 elements and you wish to store 10 of something in the array, you will simply have to manually index the sub-arrays providing multiples of `10 * sizeof(type)` which is exactly what pointer-arithmetic does for you. Effectively you will be addressing within the 1D array as if you had declared a pointer to an array of `total/n` elements and then allocated for `n` of them. (e.g. `char (*s)[10];` if you were to analogize breaking your 100 character storage up for 10 strings)

Take a trivial example of a 100-char array that you want to use to store and sort 10-10 char strings (9-char + the *nul-terminating* character). You could simply declare `char s[100] = "";` and then store your strings at offsets of `s + n * 10`. To sort the array, you could roll-your-own sort or just use `qsort` to sort your elements by providing a proper compare function. The following does just that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NROW 10
#define NCOL NROW

/* qsort - string comparison */
int cmpstrings (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp ((char * )a, (char *)b);
}

int main (void) {

    char s[NROW * NCOL] = "";       /* 1D array 100 chars */

    strcpy (s, "my");               /* fill with 10 strings */
    strcpy (s + NROW, "dog");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 2, "has");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 3, "fleas");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 4, "but");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 5, "the");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 6, "cat");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 7, "doesn't");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 8, "have");
    strcpy (s + NROW * 9, "any");

    printf ("unsorted:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NROW; i++)
        printf ("  s[%2d] : %s\n", i, &s[i*NCOL]);

    qsort (s, NCOL, NROW, cmpstrings);  /* qsort strings */

    printf ("\nsorted:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NROW; i++)
        printf ("  s[%2d] : %s\n", i, &s[i*NCOL]);

}
```

(**note:** `strcpy` was just used as a convenience to load the individual strings in the array. You could just as easily have initialized the array with the 100 characters specified in an initializer)

For example, you could have used the following initializer and eliminated the calls to `strcpy` altogether -- just a bit more tedious...

```
    /* initialize 100-char array with 10 sub-arrays of strings */
    char s[] = "my\0       dog\0      has\0      fleas\0    but\0      "
               "the\0      cat\0      doesn't\0  have\0     any\0      ";
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array1dstrings
unsorted:
  s[ 0] : my
  s[ 1] : dog
  s[ 2] : has
  s[ 3] : fleas
  s[ 4] : but
  s[ 5] : the
  s[ 6] : cat
  s[ 7] : doesn't
  s[ 8] : have
  s[ 9] : any

sorted:
  s[ 0] : any
  s[ 1] : but
  s[ 2] : cat
  s[ 3] : doesn't
  s[ 4] : dog
  s[ 5] : fleas
  s[ 6] : has
  s[ 7] : have
  s[ 8] : my
  s[ 9] : the
```

C doesn't place any limitations on how you use a block of memory as long as you don't attempt to access memory outside the valid block. It's up to you to use an addressing scheme that accomplishes that. The 2D array simply provides a convenient way to avoid having to come up with that addressing scheme on your own.

Answer (score -1):

There is some dispute as to whether this is strictly legal C11, but code such as that below is quite commonplace:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int a1[100]; 
int (*a2)[10] = (int (*)[10])a1; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) a1[i] = i + 1; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) { 
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) { 
                        printf("%2d ", a2[i][j]); 
                } 
                printf("\n"); 
        } 
}
```

You could make it strictly conforming, but a bit less convenient, by replacing a2 with:

```
#define a2(x,y) a1[10*(x)+(y)]
```

and then replace `a2[x][y]` with `a2(x,y)`. Or use a function, but that costs you function call overhead (or make an `inline` function).

Comment: While this conversion is appealing and may work in most C implementations with flat address spaces, the C standard does not generally define the behavior of using a non-character pointer converted from another pointer type except that it compares equal when converted back.

Comment: I'm not so sure whether this strictly violates the standard or not, but I *am* sure that any compiler that this *didn't* work on I would consider seriously broken, and this *does* pass `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. (Except for the unused argv/argc).

Comment: There is no warning because the conversion itself is legal. Using the converted pointer is not legal, but GCC apparently does not match the use of the pointer with its tainted origin. The behavior of pointer conversions is mostly described in C 2011 6.3.2.3. (There are other statements scattered around the standard, such as converting a pointer to the first element of a struct to a pointer to the struct.)

Comment: Hmm. I'm still not convinced. Multi-dimentional arrays created with malloc() and accessed by appropriately-cast pointers are as old as C itself. The fact that this is allocated statically doesn't seem significant to me. The standard does guarantee that arrays are contiguous--including arrays of arrays--and I'm accessing each element as an int, exactly as it was allocated, so I really don't see how any runtime could have a problem with this without itself violating the standard. I'll take a look at your reference.

Comment: The C standard goes to some trouble to define effective types for allocated storage, in contrast to declared types for other storage. Even so, aliasing violations can occur when reading allocated storage with a type other than its last stored type, and pointer conversion issues can still occur. Reasoning about contiguous allocation is inapplicable because the standard does not define general rules about pointer behavior as a function of storage location. The problem is that nothing in the standard says the result of `(int (*)[10])a1` is a valid pointer to an array of ten `int`.

Comment: If `(int (*)[10])a1` were a valid pointer, you might have an argument there is no aliasing violation. But all the C standard says about the result of that cast is that we can convert it back, and the result will equal `a1`. The standard does not say the result is otherwise usable.

Comment: This answer could be okay if it stated this is not strictly conforming C. But it is unnecessary, because the problem can be solved by using a proxy function that, given two indices, looks up elements in the one-dimensional array.

Comment: Perhaps, but everywhere I look in the standard (including 6.3.2.3.7) it says that conversion of pointer types is undefined only when their underlying types have different alignment. In the absence of an absolute black-and-white statement by the standard, I'll have to fall back on 30+ years of practice and convention, where code like this is commonplace and well understood.

Comment: Yes, it could be done with a function, or a macro that resolves to `*(a + 10 * x + y)`. But `a[x][y]` is clearer, what the OP asked for, and I still think legal until I hear a more convincing argument. I'll add a caveat.

Comment: Once again, it is not the conversion that is undefined. It is perfectly legal to convert. It is using the resulting pointer that is not defined. When you look at 6.3.2.3 7, do you see anything that says the result of the conversion actually points to **an object**? Do you any statement about what the result of the conversion is other than it can be converted back and will then compare equal? What that supports is passing pointers temporarily through other types, since C does not support polymorphism. It is not for using converted pointers.

Comment: What polymorphism? The address of an array of 10 ints *is* the address of its first element, by definition, which is the address of an int, exactly the same type as we started with. I am dereferencing a pointer to int to fetch an int that was put there via a pointer to int. I added your warning, but I'm sorry, I'm just not buying your argument. "The spec doesn't explicitly allow..." doesn't impress me. Show me either "The spec specifically forbids...", or else show a single implementation on some platform anywhere in which this doesn't do exactly what we all know it does.

Comment: I have already shown that the passage in the C standard describing pointer conversions does not define the result of the conversion in question. You are merely claiming you do not think the standard means that and not providing any evidence for it. I have shown where the gap in the C standard is—there is no phrase in that passage that says what the result of the conversion is. It is unreasonable to ask for a demonstration where undefined behavior acts in a way other than you specify—it is undefined, and I have no control over it.

Comment: We can, however, show that your model of pointers as addresses is flawed. 6.2.4 2 says “The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.” That does not mean that referring to the object the pointer pointed to, as by dereferencing it is illegal (that is in the previous sentence). It says the **value** of the pointer itself becomes indeterminate. But it is clearly impossible for the bits to have changed; nothing happens to the bits in a pointer when it is passed to `free` or the routine it was created in exits.

Comment: Thus, according to the C standard, there is something more to whether a pointer has a valid value than merely what address it points to in memory.

Comment: I do appreciate your engagement here, I really do, but this last bit is really deliberately obtuse. *Of course* a pointer is invalid after it goes out of scope, regardless of having the same bits, because it now points to memory that is free for other use. That doesn't do anything like "invalidate the pointer as address" model, it just states the obvious that you can't use memory that you no longer own. I am leaving this discussion, and I am leaving the answer as written. If you like, I've started a thread on comp.lang.c about the issue. So far the only commenter agrees with you.